# jmeter functions and variables from csv not substituting

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a POST request setup in jmeter that has a body like:

```
  "chartId": ${chartid},
  "source": "Direct 5",
  "documentId": ${__counter},
```

__counter is a built in function and chartid should be coming from CSV:

[image]

However, they are not being substituted in the request.  I'm using the latest jmeter (5.5) with Java 8.

Can anyone think of anything I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. `${__counter}` is not a built-in function, `${__counter(,)}` is. Use [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) if you're uncertain regarding proper functions syntax.
2. I cannot comment anything regarding `${chartid}` unless I see first 2 lines of your CSV file and the rest of configuration of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), in the meantime you can see all JMeter Variables which are defined with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

Comment: That fixed the counter!  Thank you.

One of the CSV setups is shown above in the original post, and the first two lines of that file are:


    clientid,csgid,chart
    2,41,5983

Comment: Actually, that fixed everything, thank you so much!